# Unity Scripting armv7 Error

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I'm attempting to write my first unity script. This is the code for a file called TestPlugin.cs that is located in Assets/Plugins:

```
using UnityEngine; 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class TestPlugin : MonoBehaviour 
{
    [DllImport ("__Internal")]
    private static extern int getString ();

    public static void Awake () {
      print (getString ());
    }
}
```

This is the code for two files that I import into the generated xCode project's classes folder:

**TestPlugin.h:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TestPlugin : NSObject

-(int)getString;

@end
```

**TestPlugin.m:**

```
#import "TestPlugin.h"

@implementation TestPlugin

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

- (int)getString
{
    return 7;
}

@end
```

Finally this is the javascript file that sits inside the Asset folder.

TestPluginTest.js:

```
function Update () 
{
TestPlugin.Awake ();
}
```

Also, please note that i'm not necessarily expecting this all to work, just to compile at this point (though extra pointers and tips are welcome)

The error I get in xCode when trying to build onto iPhone (actual device) is this:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:   "_getString", referenced
>   from:
>         RegisterMonoModules()     in RegisterMonoModules.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> "_getString", referenced from:
>
> RegisterMonoModules()     in RegisterMonoModules.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I'm stumped! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the Obj-C interface because the linker does not know how to handle the signature. When I connected a self written library I designed the interface to contain pure C code only:

interface.h

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
#endif    
    int getString();        
#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
#endif
```

interface.c:

```
int getString() {
    // do something
}
```

Maybe useful blog postings:

[iPhone & Unity3D: Integrating 3rd Party Static Libraries in Unity3D Generated XCode Projects](http://www.scio.de/en/blog-a-neues/scio-development-blog/entry/iphone-a-unity3d-integrating-3rd-party-static-libraries-in-unity3d-generated-xcode-projects)

[Unity Native Plugins: OS X](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/unity-native-plugins-os-x/)

[Clever Martian's Blog - An Experiment with iPhone Native UI and Unity 3 Pro](https://web.archive.org/web/20120801062200/http://clevermartian.com/blog/?p=59)

Comment: so the problem is that it's written in objective c?

Comment: This actually fixed the problem, but the problem is I actually need to write the interface in objective C. Is this not recommended?

Comment: Unity says no according to http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Plugins.html Don't get me wrong: you can of course write your plugin code in Obj-C, but you need a wrapper interface in plain C for C# / JS calling the plugin. My library has > 50 classes but one lean C interface.